# How does combat damage work when one creature blocks multiple attackers?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

If I have [Brave the Sands](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Brave%20the%20Sands), am I allowed to block both a 6/6 flying and a 5/4 with my 1/2 [Gurmag Swiftwing](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Gurmag%20Swiftwing), and take 0 damage?

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what you're asking here. Do you want to know whether a card that says that your creatures can each block an additional creature lets a blocker block two creatures, or whether blocking creatures prevents them from dealing damage to you, or something else?

Comment: I'm sorry Murgatroid, I want to know if it is legal for me to block both of these creatures with something with only 2 toughness or if I will need enough toughness to survive at least on of the attacking creatures. I am aware I can block 2 creatures it just seems strange to be able to block 2 strong creatures with only a 1/2. Thank you for your time.

Comment: Consider the example of [Hundred-Handed One](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=373708). While it is monstrous, it can block 100 creatures, but it is never expected to actually reach 100 toughness.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Yes, the combination of cards you described allows you to block both creatures.**

Since Brave the Sands allows you to declare your creature as a blocker for 2 separate attackers, both will be considered blocked, your Swiftwing will die, and you will receive no damage. Declaring blockers does not require that your creature be able to survive combat with any of the attackers, and both declarations and damage happen simultaneously, so there's no point where your creature will be destroyed "before" it can block the other attacker.

A couple things worth noting:

When a creature blocks multiple attackers, the defending player chooses the order in which the blocking creature's damage is dealt. In your example it doesn't make much difference since your creature couldn't kill either attacker, but if you were blocking instead with a 4/4 creature, you could either deal 4 damage to the 5/4 and destroy it, or you could deal 4 damage to the 6/6 in hopes of damaging it later that turn.

If either attacker has trample, any damage beyond your creature's toughness can be assigned to you.

Comment: Thank you very much, I can't believe the amazing people on this website!

Comment: It would be useful to add in a brief note about assigning attacker-order during the Declare Blockers step.

Comment: That sounds like a separate question and answer Hao Ye.

Comment: @LovesTha Not really - ordering attackers when a single creature is blocking multiple attackers directly affects how combat damage will occur.

Comment: @AverageUnknown "A couple things worth *nothing*" ?? :D

Comment: @Ian Heh. Oops.